# Non-differentiability of a Markov diffusion process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

I was reading through these notes [(link here)](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~pavl/lec_diff_proc.pdf) on Markov diffusion processes and I'm confused about one of the definitions and its properties.

It is stated that the Markov diffusion process satisfies the continuity condition in that $P(|X_t - X_s | \ge \epsilon | X_s = x) = o(t-s)$. It then goes on to say that this condition implies that the sample paths of a diffusion process are not differentiable.

I am confused by this statement. From what I understand, the $o$-notation here means that $\lim_{t\rightarrow s} \frac{o(t-s)}{t-s} = 0$. For example, we have that $x^5$ is $o(x)$ as $x\rightarrow 0$. This makes me think that if $f(x)$ is $o(x)$ as $x \rightarrow 0$, i.. the rate of decay of $f(x)$ compared to that of $x$ is faster as $x \rightarrow 0$.

Hence, I do not understand why in the link it says: "the sample paths of a diffusion process
are not differentiable : if
they where, then the right hand side of the above equation would
have to be 0 when  $t-s \ll 1$ ".

Can anyone help me show (more rigorously) how this implies that $P(\frac{|X_t - X_s |}{t-s} \ge \epsilon | X_s = x) $ does not approach 0 as $t \rightarrow s$?